# UIImageView and UIWebView in one viewcontroller

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

Is it possible to have both UIImageView and UIWebView in one UIViewController? Or how do I add UIImageView as SubView to UIWebView. I tried to create it in storyboard but when I run the program, the image in UIImageView is not displaying, only the htmlstring for UIWebview.

Answer (score 0):

You can have them both handled by a single view controller by making them both subviews of the view controller's main view and arranging them within it.

I'm less certain about creating subviews of a UIWebView since it's not just a simple view but one that's already composed with its own subviews.

Comment: Can you help me how to do it programmatically? I tried to do it as  [self.view addSubview:imageView];                           [self.view addSubview:webView]; in loadView but it crashed.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with those two lines.  What does the crash/exception say?

Answer (score 0):

Include both UIImageView and UIWebView in a root UIView. Define properties to control both views from your UIViewController.